# incoming email in postfix centos 7 server not getting inbox

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, centos7

I'm using Centos 7 and postfix. While I can send email from my server but I can't read email because not getting emails in my postfix "maildir" than I command to check mail logs -

```
[root@server ~]# tail -f /var/log/maillog
Oct  9 09:59:43 server postfix/cleanup[17670]: 5B4DF2A0B52: message-id=<20181009075943.5B4DF2A0B52@server.azahar.in>
Oct  9 09:59:43 server postfix/bounce[17673]: 8BA892A0A57: sender non-delivery notification: 5B4DF2A0B52
Oct  9 09:59:43 server postfix/qmgr[17266]: 5B4DF2A0B52: from=<>, size=4929, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  9 09:59:43 server postfix/qmgr[17266]: 8BA892A0A57: removed
Oct  9 09:59:44 server postfix/smtpd[17645]: disconnect from sonic302-19.consmr.mail.sg3.yahoo.com[106.10.242.139]
Oct  9 09:59:45 server postfix/smtp[17674]: 5B4DF2A0B52: to=<funaua@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[74.6.137.63]:25, delay=2.5, delays=0/0.02/1/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Oct  9 09:59:45 server postfix/qmgr[17266]: 5B4DF2A0B52: removed
Oct  9 10:03:04 server postfix/anvil[17648]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:106.10.242.139) at Oct  9 09:59:40
Oct  9 10:03:04 server postfix/anvil[17648]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:106.10.242.139) at Oct  9 09:59:40
Oct  9 10:03:04 server postfix/anvil[17648]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Oct  9 09:59:40
```

I think emails are automatically removing from my server.

Please check the logs and provide me proper solutions to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The log snippet you posted is a "sender non-delivery notification", it means that you were notified that an email you attempted to send was bounced.

From the [Postfix manual](http://www.postfix.org/bounce.8.html):

> ```
>    The bounce(8) daemon maintains per-message log files with delivery sta-
>    tus information. Each log file is named after the queue  file  that  it
>    corresponds  to,  and  is  kept in a queue subdirectory named after the
>    service name in the master.cf file (either  bounce,  defer  or  trace).
>    This program expects to be run from the master(8) process manager.
> ```

```
   The bounce(8) daemon processes two types of service requests:

   o      Append a recipient (non-)delivery status record to a per-message
          log file.

   o      Enqueue a delivery status notification message, with a copy of a
          per-message log file and of the corresponding message.  When the
          delivery status notification message is  enqueued  successfully,
          the per-message log file is deleted.

   The  software does a best notification effort. A non-delivery notifica-
   tion is sent even when the log file or the original message  cannot  be
   read.
```

Running your own email server is super complicated, and unless absolutely necessary, I'd advise against it and just pay someone else to do it. (Gmail, Office365, Fastmail, etc…) Besides just getting the daemon to function correctly, there are several layers of security to deal with, many of which are easy to get wrong. If you don't play your cards just right, you could easily open your email server up as a spam relay. Then you'll get blocked, and then you won't be sending anyone anything for a while.